# Por que utilizar Kernel#loop ao invés de begin-end-while/until?

Tags: ruby, loop, while

Estou fazendo uma estrutura de repetição em Ruby utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

```
begin
  [código]
end <while/until> [condição]
```

Porém o [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop), que uso como ferramenta de *linting*, diz que eu deveria utilizar o `Kernel#loop` com `break`. Assim:

```
loop do
  [código]
  break <if/unless> [condição]
end
```

Por que? Em que casos deveria ser utilizado o `begin-end-while/until`? Quais vantagens o `Kernel#loop` acima traz em relação à estrutura que eu utilizei?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sou especialista em Ruby, mas pelo que vi é só questão de legibilidade.

Quando você vai lendo o código e encontra um `begin` fica pensando, começo de que? Não tem nada indicando claramente ali. Pior, pode ser que algum caso o próprio compilador pode achar que ali é o começo de algo anterior e ficar muito errado.

Usando o `loop` fica explícito que ali começa um laço e mais fácil de acompanhar o fluxo e entender o que está acontecendo.

Eu acho interessante levantar o problemas, mas não gosto da sugestão oferecida, ela sequer tem a mesma semântica do código original, então induz a erro se a pessoa não entender o que está fazendo. Mas infelizmente a linguagem não oferece uma opção melhor.